# How can I move the view in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I zoom a lot and need to move the current viewport...is there a way to move it with mouse wheel click like in other programs?

Currently I must go to the scrolling bars for adjusting X and Y view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply hold down the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and then click-drag with the mouse.

You could also use the **Navigator Panel**, but I find the spacebar far more efficient.